# ReactJS synthetic event for hit-state?

Tags: reactjs, accessibility

I recently did something like this

```
onHit(functionCall)
{
    let attr = {};
    attr["onKeyPress"] = functionCall;
    attr["onClick"] = functionCall;
    attr["onTouchEnd"] = functionCall;
    return attr;
}
```

So that I can do this in my JSX

```
<a {...this.onHit((e)=>this.doSomething())} title="This has no href" tabIndex="0">This has no href</a>
```

Everything works as expected, where keypress, click, and touchdown all trigger the same event.

I created this `onHit` function because I'm building a web application where all action controls need to be accessible by keyboard, mouse and touch screen.

Before I continue using my custom `onHit` function, is there a more idiomatic way of doing this in ReactJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution is nice, but you could also create a custom component that takes the component/element type as prop, the `onHit` function as prop and uses that as event handler for all events, and that spreads the rest of the props.

**Example**

```js
function MyComponent({ element: Element, onHit, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Element onKeyPress={onHit} onClick={onHit} onTouchEnd={onHit} {...rest} />
  );
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyComponent
        element={"a"}
        onHit={() => console.log("hit!")}
        title="This has no href"
        tabIndex="0"
      >
        This has no href
      </MyComponent>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```